# Visual Leak Detector detects leak on new blank MFC project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, memory-leaks

I recently installed VLD to try and debug a C++ MDI MFC application in Visual Studio 2008. VLD reported a memory leak and no matter what I did I could not correct the issue, so I created a brand new blank project (MDi MFC) and the memory leak is still showing up. The only modification I made was writing `#include <vld.h>` in the main `Project.h` file. The documentation says it doesn't matter which file, so here is the output after execution (Simply selecting File/Exit and doing nothing else).

```
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\MasterHD\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Project\Debug\Project.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.debugmfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_9b54853441e399d5\mfc90ud.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_96748342450f6aa2\msvcr90d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msimg32.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\bin\Win32\vld_x86.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\bin\Win32\dbghelp.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfcloc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_49768ef57548175e\MFC90ENU.DLL', Binary was not built with debug information.
Visual Leak Detector Version 2.4RC2 installed.
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'
'Project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'
WARNING: Visual Leak Detector detected memory leaks!
---------- Block 981 at 0x005BF560: 48 bytes ----------
  Leak Hash: 0x32D8578B, Count: 1, Total 48 bytes
  Call Stack (TID 9552):
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c (159): MSVCR90D.dll!_malloc_dbg
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\afxmem.cpp (407): mfc90ud.dll!operator new + 0x16 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\afxmem.cpp (61): mfc90ud.dll!operator new + 0x13 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\tooltip.cpp (479): mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::FilterToolTipMessage + 0x11 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\tooltip.cpp (374): mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::_FilterToolTipMessage
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\wincore.cpp (1070): mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::PreTranslateMessage
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\barcore.cpp (372): mfc90ud.dll!CControlBar::PreTranslateMessage + 0xC bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\wincore.cpp (2946): mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::WalkPreTranslateTree + 0x14 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp (233): mfc90ud.dll!AfxInternalPreTranslateMessage + 0x12 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp (777): mfc90ud.dll!CWinThread::PreTranslateMessage + 0x9 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp (252): mfc90ud.dll!AfxPreTranslateMessage + 0x11 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp (178): mfc90ud.dll!AfxInternalPumpMessage + 0x18 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp (900): mfc90ud.dll!CWinThread::PumpMessage
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp (629): mfc90ud.dll!CWinThread::Run + 0xD bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\appcore.cpp (865): mfc90ud.dll!CWinApp::Run
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\winmain.cpp (47): mfc90ud.dll!AfxWinMain + 0xD bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\appmodul.cpp (30): Project.exe!wWinMain
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (574): Project.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x35 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (399): Project.exe!wWinMainCRTStartup
    0x76D8338A (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
    0x77719F72 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
    0x77719F45 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes
  Data:
    2C 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    F2 19 BA 00    00 E1 00 00     ,....... ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    18 00 00 00    17 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    FF FF FF FF    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........


Visual Leak Detector detected 1 memory leak (1016 bytes).
Largest number used: 14482 bytes.
Total allocations: 1681878 bytes.
Visual Leak Detector is now exiting.
The program '[14684] Project.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Anyone have any insights or suggestions? I can't even pinpoint what is causing the memory leak here, let alone in my actual project.

**EDIT:** If I close the application using the "X" in the top-right corner, then **NO** memory leak occurs, but when I use the File/Exit drop-down menu, it always shows 1016 Bytes leak.

Comment: I can't say if this memory leak is a false positive or not, but I can say that I also get exactly the _same_ leak message when using VS2005 (sames paths, different line numbers because I'm still using mfc80ud.dll) with the _latest_ version of VLD (v2.4rc2) obtained from the codeplex site. The leak does _not_ appear when using v2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty late to this but I just ran into the same leak using visual studio 2013 and using the crtdbg leak detection. It appears that PreTranslateMessage calls into FilterToolTipMessage during the main windows message processing loop. This then has the leak at the following spot

```
if (pToolTip == NULL)
{
  pToolTip = new CToolTipCtrl;
  if (!pToolTip->Create(pOwner, TTS_ALWAYSTIP))
  ...
}
```

The only point I see where it is cleaned up is if the following create call fails. If it does not fail, then I don't see any other cleanup for this object.

code is located in "Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\tooltip.cpp". In the version I have its line 416

Comment: Same here - I get it at line 479 of tooltip.cpp in Visual Studio 2012.